# Is this homebrew magic item, the Necklace of Peer Pressure, balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, balance, homebrew-review

The intent of this item is to provide a version of the spell *Suggestion* that is stronger than the base spell but not as powerful as *Mass Suggestion*. The party members who would receive this item will be 5th-7th level, this item may be used in or out of combat. Is this item appropriately balanced for use as a rare item?

> **Necklace of Peer Pressure**
>
> *Wondrous Item, Rare (Requires Attunement)*
>
> This appears to be a necklace made of polished puka shells. In order
> for the abilities of the necklace to be activated, the necklace must
> be worn and clearly visible. The necklace can hold a maximum of seven
> charges, and it regains one charge each dawn.
>
> When the necklace is activated, you cast a version of *Mass
> Suggestion* with the following limitations:
>
> You suggest a course of activity (limited to a sentence or two) and
> expend one or more charges to magically influence up to seven
> creatures (one creature per charge expended) of your choice that you can see within range and that can hear and understand you.
>
> Each target must make a DC 15 Wisdom saving throw. On a failed save, it pursues the course of action you described to the best of its ability for the next 12 hours.

Comment: Is the only difference here that you provide an upcast option for *suggestion*? Is there a reason why you aren't actually casting *suggestion* to have it include all the other rights and responsibilities of spells? And what are checking balance against here? Other Rare items?

Comment: Also, how do you currently treat *suggestion*. This spell is very table/ruling dependent and understanding how much leeway you currently provide will go a long way to letting you know more about this particular item.

Comment: @NautArch I meant for this to actually cast a spell, though I realize that the wording can be misleading. I am not looking for guidance on what constitutes a "reasonable" action with respect to Suggestion. I was using the Horn of Valhalla (Silver/Brass) as a guideline for maximum frequency of use, but wanted to allow a mechanic where PCs could customize their usage and opt to cast less powerful Suggestion/Mass Suggestion more frequently. This item's effect should top out around a 4th level spell (halfway between the two spells)

Comment: You don't actually say that it's casting *suggestion*, though. If it's doing that, you should be saying that the necklace is casting it (or have it be some other mechanic - but it needs to be clear that there is casting because castings can be counterspelled.) But again, in order for us to look at balance/power, we need to know strict you are in your rulings on acceptable suggestions. PLease also let us know what we're judging balance against.

Comment: @NautArch I have edited the listing to reflect that it should cast a version of Mass Suggestion

Comment: If you're having it cast the spell, you can simply reference that and not include the spell language (because that's in the spell.) That simplifies the block immensely and lets us focus on the mechanics of regen and upcast.

Comment: But having said that, we still need to know how you typically rule on suggestions, including whether or not you allow them in combat (and what do you allow). THis along with what you're asking for judging balance against are necessary (in my opinion)

Comment: Please only include the factors which makes it different from a standard *mass suggestion* and describe them as such; I believe the only thing is duration and number of targets. (+ specify DC). Also, is the number of targets 7 + 1 per additional charge spend? This is very confusingly written as of now.

Comment: @Someone_Evil The number of targets should be 1-7 in total depending on the number of charges expended, and this has been corrected in an earlier edit.

Comment: Ahh, the new text is much clearer. I still think you should move the duration clause from the top (where it actually makes no sense for a magic item) and you can replace the last paragraph with a simple (Spell save DC 15) on the spell, the rest in that par is already stated in the item or spell description.

Answer (score 8):

Suggestion and its 'Mass' equivalent are two very contextual spells that can really, seriously shift certain kinds of games. A succesful cast of this spell on the right target is sometimes a real game changer.

In other games, players rarely have opportunities to use charm spells.

So it's kind of hard to answer this one without more information about the kind of game you are running.

In a game of political intrigue it is a really good spell, even if the target knows it has been charmed afterwards ... so having "unrestricted" access to this spell without having to learn it and use a slot to prepare it everyday can be overpowered, because it opens up a lot of possibilities for the group to just "magic their way to victory" more often than would otherwise be possible and without the cost of having to chose this option over another.

Side personal note: As a DM, I'm on the fence to decide if I would, or not, hand out this item as it is. I think I'd give it less charges and a slower recharge rate, because I'd be worried about my players potentially casting a maximum of 14 Suggestions in the first week (assuming they get it fully charged) or 7 Suggestions on the first 'big day, story wise'. But I also could have a lot of fun rolling with it and having their 'victims' seek out revenge for what they forced them to do.